# Ag-grid gridApi.gridOptionsWrapper depricated, how to use it

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I have an enterprise level application which has multiple ag-grid in it (approx 30). We use angular and we have a common service that does all the export and copy related modifications to grid data in one place.

**Older Implementation**
We used `gridApi.gridOptionsWrapper.setProperty('processeaderForClipboard',())` to process our column headers that had multi level groupings and then copy them.

**In v30**
The gridoptionswrapper seems to be removed in recent ag-grid update how can i process the column names including column groups before exporting.

Here with process i mean, in most cases we have abbreviations for certain terms, we get those from resources, something some columns have date type etc.

I tried to explore the documentation but was unable to find any resources for same.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I know i had to use gridOptionsService instead of gridOptionsWrapper within a cell editor to get the grid options.

> this.params.column.gridOptionsService

Maybe you need to check out for a property named gridOptionsService.